# Ruby modules and tracker variables within a module

Tags: ruby, module

My module:

```
module Httpserver
    failures = []
    passes = []

    def self.validate(type, file)
        File.open('01httpserver.txt', 'a') do |out|
            if type == "asa"
                if File.readlines(file).grep(/http server enabled/).any?
                     #failures =+ file
                     out.puts "FAILED: #{file} does have http enabled"
                else
                     #passes =+ file
                     out.puts "PASSED: #{file} does not have http enabled"
                end
            elsif type == "ios"
                if File.readlines(file).grep(/no ip http server/).any?
                    #failures =+ file
                    out.puts "FAILED: #{file} does have http enabled"
                else
                    #passes =+ file
                    out.puts "PASSED: #{file} does not have http enabled"
                end
            end
        end
    end

    def self.close
        File.open('01httpserver.txt', 'a') do |out|
            out.puts "\n"
            failures.each do |failure|
                out.puts failure
            end
        end
    end
end
```

My main script calling the module:

```
asa_files.each do |file|
    Httpserver.validate("asa", file)
    Httpserver.close()
end
```

Now I want to track all the failures so if I uncomment the "failures =+ file" lines or the "passes =+ file" lines.  I get the following error.

```
01httpserver.rb:12:in `block in validate': undefined method `+@' for "bucket/config.txt":String (NoMethodError)
from /Users/****/modules/01httpserver.rb:6:in `open'
from /Users/****/modules/01httpserver.rb:6:in `validate'
from cis.rb:40:in `block in <main>'
from cis.rb:39:in `each'
from cis.rb:39:in `<main>'
```

Is this not a proper way to track the failures of just the items being checked in this module?  Should I have an array in the main script and add to that array instead?  Please let me know if this does not make sense.

Comment: Okay so I changed them all to be either failures.push(file) of passes.push(file).  However now it's saying "/Users/****/modules/01httpserver.rb:14:in `block in validate': undefined local variable or method `passes' for Httpserver:Module (NameError)".  So it doesn't understand or recognize the failures or passes variables.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is interpreting `=+` as an assignment followed by an unary `+` operator, which is not defined on String. You're probably looking for `+=`.

**Edit**, sorry, I misinterpreted the error message. Use `<<` or `push` as Alex suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `failures =+ file`. The correct operator is `+=`, not `=+`.

The correct way to add an element to an array is `failures.push(file)`.